# How to copy a file to a directory if not exists there (and not copy if exists) by groovy(gradle)

Tags: gradle, groovy, copy

I want to **copy a file to a directory if not exists there** with groovy(Gradle) by the following command:

```
from(<source>){
    into <destination>
}
```

- Is there any option to check if the file exists there or not? or not replace it if exists?
- Or is there any other command to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
task copySomeFiles(type: Copy) {
    duplicatesStrategy= DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
    from 'from/path'
    into 'to/path'
}
```

DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE states that files should not be overwritten

docs:https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html